# getting error in bigquery while creating a model

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting this error after running a model creation query:
`All time series failed to fit, likely because they are all invalid. Please run auto-arima on each time series to find out the root cause based on the returned error message.`

I have used the following code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL gs_analytics_dataset.arima_model
    
    OPTIONS(
      MODEL_TYPE='ARIMA_PLUS',
      TIME_SERIES_TIMESTAMP_COL='date', 
      TIME_SERIES_DATA_COL='total_amount',
      TIME_SERIES_ID_COL='store_id',
      HOLIDAY_REGION='US'
    ) AS
    
    SELECT 
        store_id,
        date,
        total_amount
    FROM
      gs_analytics_dataset.revenue
```

Comment: what data type is the `date` column?

Comment: it's of datatype date

Comment: did you try using a timestamp column rather than a date column? `CAST(date AS TIMESTAMP) date,`  in the select part?

Comment: where should I make changes, can you please make it a bit more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Not used this type of model before, but the error seems to point to an issue with the timeseries (which you have give a date to - the option name implies that it wants a timestamp).

Try changing your statement to provide a timestamp

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL gs_analytics_dataset.arima_model

OPTIONS(
  MODEL_TYPE='ARIMA_PLUS',
  TIME_SERIES_TIMESTAMP_COL='ts', 
  TIME_SERIES_DATA_COL='total_amount',
  TIME_SERIES_ID_COL='store_id',
  HOLIDAY_REGION='US'
) AS

SELECT 
    store_id,
    CAST(date AS TIMESTAMP) ts,
    total_amount
FROM
  gs_analytics_dataset.revenue
```

Comment: still the same error is coming

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-build-demand-forecasting-models-bigquery-ml

Comment: This is the official link for model forecating thing given on google cloud.